# Javascript Object return all key value pairs but only top 5 values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an object that looks like this

```js
res = {
  ID_COL: "SAME_START_DATE",
  ID_TBL: "MQL_FIELD_VALUE",
  SUBSCRIBERS: [
    2255967,
    839748,
    957525,
    758813,
    4062601,
    1085163,
    414789,
    765855,
    4135634,
    599436,
    322862,
    2782575,
    1318088,
    3810363,
  ]
}
```

I want to return this full object with all key/value pairs but limit the array (the IDs in `SUBSCRIBERS`) to just the top 5. How can I do this?

I've tried `return Object.values(res)[0].slice(0,5);` but am unsure how to get the rest of the key/value pairs (ID_COL and ID_TBL) in the object as well.

Comment: Why do you use `slice`? Remove it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Does `{ ...res, SUBSCRIBERS: res.SUBSCRIBERS.slice(0, 5) }` do the trick?

Comment: by top 5 you mean the top 5 highest numbers in the `SUBSCRIBERS` array? or just the 1st five values that can be seen on the array?

Comment: the 1st five values are fine, it doesn't have to be the highest 5 numbers. so essentially would return: 
`
{
  ID_COL: "SAME_START_DATE",
  ID_TBL: "MQL_FIELD_VALUE",
  SUBSCRIBERS: [
    2255967,
    839748,
    957525,
    758813,
    4062601
  ]
}`

Answer (score -1):

```js
let res = {
  ID_COL: "SAME_START_DATE",
  ID_TBL: "MQL_FIELD_VALUE",
  SUBSCRIBERS: [
    2255967,
    839748,
    957525,
    758813,
    4062601,
    1085163,
    414789,
    765855,
    4135634,
    599436,
    322862,
    2782575,
    1318088,
    3810363,
  ]
};

Object.keys(res).forEach(function(key, index) {
  if (key == 'SUBSCRIBERS') {
     res[key] = res[key].slice(0,5);
  } else {
    res[key];
  }
});

console.log(res);
```